# Why "lengths of 'x' and 'y' must be the same" error in cor.test?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, correlation

That below code makes error.

> Error in cor.test.default(bp$bmi[bp$year == j], bp$i[bp$year == j]) : 
>   "lengths of 'x' and 'y' must be the same"

There are no NA or NULL values in my data.

If I changed `bp$i` to `bp$sbp` or `bp$dbp` and run separately, it works well.

But if I put loop code i ; it doesn't work. I don't know why..

```
corr <-data.frame(matrix(nrow=1, ncol=4))
names(corr)=c("bp", "year","coefficient","P-value")

e=1
for (i in c("sbp","dbp")){
  for (j in c("2002","2005","2008","2011","2014","2017")){
    result <- cor.test(bp$bmi[bp$year==j], bp$i[bp$year==j])
    corr[e,1]<-i
    corr[e,2]<-j
    corr[e,3]<-round(result$estimate,3)
    corr[e,4]<-round(result$p.value,3)
    e<-e+1
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. We don't happen to have your `bp` data.frame. Without it, it's very difficult to reproduce your error and provide a solution. Please edit your question and paste the result of `dput(head(bp))`

Comment: The problem is `bp$i` , which I am guessing returns nothing at the moment. You can't use `$` with variable strings to get to the column name stored in `i`. Try `bp[[i]]` instead.

Comment: This is not reproducible without the data. You do not seem to understand how R works. It is not a macro language. In bp$i, i does not get substituted with "sbp" or "dbp". R expects to find a variable (column) named i inside the data frame bp. Also it is usually possible to avoid loops for simple tasks like this.

Comment: Thank you . When I changed bp$i to bp[[i]] , it worked well. And sorry for without data.